# How to auto-populate MS Access database fields?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an assignment to create and test database specifically on Microsoft Access. I have layed out architecture of it that means I have created tables and relations.

Yet I am not feeling ultra excited about filling every table with content copying and pasting fro lorem ipsum page...

Can a MS Access database be automatically populated with random content? If so how?

Comment: You could write a VBA program to populate it - better than the manual tedium alternative, and you may learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to generate random test data is to do it in Excel and then copy/paste into Access.

If you're populating user records, then you can use http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/ which will create huge users lists of totally fake data with almost any attribute you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use microsoft online templates. See the below screenshot

[image]