# How to Populate MS Access With Fake Data

Tags: ms-access, dummy-data

Working with a test DB in MS Access and I am looking for a way to populate my data-sets with fake test data to work on queries. Already seen [How to auto-populate MS Access database fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754518/how-to-auto-populate-ms-access-database-fields) but no progress. Are there any safe websites that can do this for free?

Comment: Use https://www.mockaroo.com/ to create yourself a bunch of data in CSV format. Import it into MS Access. There also appears to be a sample MDB database here: http://www.arialsoftware.com/blog/sample-access-mdb-database

Comment: This works great, can it enforce referential integrity?

Comment: I don't think the mock data from mockaroo.com can enforce referential integrity. You can create integrity yourself. Once you import some data into your table, create a new field called `color`. For first 100 record, type 1. For next 100, type 2...etc...and create a master table called `color_master`. Add IDs and colors in that table and add a foreign key between those 2 tables.

Comment: I'd get Northwind, the Microsoft example Access database they use in many courses. You can find instructions how to [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0410ae46-28a0-428a-bae2-4deb4c834f08/is-northwindaccdb-included-in-access-2010). Northwind includes sample data, forms, relationships, reports, macro's and modules. Many of Microsofts "how-to" examples use the Northwind database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://www.generatedata.com/ and enter the field names and the data types you want and it will generate 100 rows of data you can download.